# trying to run a cronjob with file included but when i run command line it continue saying there's an error and the files arent there

Tags: php, shell, cron

Well i am trying to run a cronjob that has some files included but when i run it through command line it keep saying the file aren't there

Here is the php file:

```
include "../includes/common.php";
require_once('../anotherfile.php');
require_once '../swift/lib/swift_required.php';

//some database things
```

here is the command line i run:

`/usr/local/bin/php /home/xxxxx/public_html/cron/somefile.php`

and here is the error i get:

```
Warning: include(..includes/common.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxxxx/public_html/cron/somefilek.php on line 3
Warning: include(..includes/common.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxxxx/public_html/cron/somefilek.php on line 3
Warning: include(): Failed opening '..includes/common.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/xxxxx/public_html/cron/somefilek.php on line 3
Warning: require_once(..anotherfile.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxxxx/public_html/cron/somefilek.php on line 4
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '..anotherfile.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/xxxxx/public_html/cron/somefilek.php on line 4
```

for some reason it says nothing about the swift_required.php

Comment: Are you sure you did not make a typo? You error says: `include(..includes/common.php)` and not `include(../includes/common.php)`

Comment: Are there nested includes ? Like common.php has an include that's not working.… I think I might be reading the error wrong.

Comment: john I've tried both ways both didn't work the ../ and just .. well common.php works for the entire site and has some includes but they are working normally

Comment: the reason it isn't saying anything about `swift_required.php` is because you have `anotherfile.php` `required` right before that not included. Since it can't include `anotherfile.php` and you `require` it the program terminates on the error. As it says `Fatal error`.

Comment: yea i figured that out thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to "posicionate" in yor directory first or use absolute path in your includes. Try changing your command to this:

```
cd /home/xxxxx/public_html/cron && /usr/local/bin/php /home/xxxxx/public_html/cron/somefile.php
```

Comment: That's so weird... are you sure the path to the files are correct and you have permissions to read it?

Comment: the paths are correct about now about premission's i'll have to check now

Comment: So the correct file path is: `/home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/common.php`

Comment: are you sure the permissions are correct when you run via command line apache isn't the user accessing the file.

Comment: The premissions are correct but there is something with the path i think I've create a test file and put it in the same folder of the cron.. from there doing `include( 'tesfile.php');` worked perfectly i then took the file from domain/con/.. to domain/.. and included it as: `include( '..tesfile.php);` this however did not work. which make me think its a path issue .. how do you go back a directory ?

Comment: If you think is a path problem, you can try to use absolute path in your includes